# Ошибка C2061 при указании аргумента функции

Tags: c++, функции, аргументы

Создаю класс (MemoryUnit), в конструкторе которого указываю другой класс (Memory). При компиляции появляется ошибка C2061. С документацией по ошибке не разобрался. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "memory.h"

using namespace std;

class MemoryUnit {
public: 
    int value;
    int weight;

    MemoryUnit();

    MemoryUnit(int, int);

    void SetMemoryUnitStack(Memory); // здесь ругается на Memory C2061  синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "Memory"   


    void FreeMemoryUnit();
};
```

Здесь только прототипы функций.

Comment: так а где ваш класс `Memory`? Он вообще существует?

Comment: Класс Memory находится в той же папке.

Comment: то что он "находится в той же папке" - мало о чем не говорит. Приведите его объявление и название файла в котором он объявлен